# Xamarin Android app calling to wcf service, System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, Position 1

Tags: wcf, xamarin.android

I've got a Xamarin Android App I'm working on with a WCF Service that I'm calling that was written by someone else.  The error I'm getting is :

```
 {System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, position 1.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object:__icall_wrapper_mono_delegate_end_invoke (object,intptr)
  at (wrapper delegate-end-invoke) <Module>:end_invoke_object__this___object[]&_IAsyncResult (object[]&,System.IAsyncResult)
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.EndProcess (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName, System.Object[] parameters, System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRuntimeChannel.cs:460 
  at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1+ChannelBase`1[TChannel,T].EndInvoke (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args, System.IAsyncResult result) [0x0003c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs:404 
  at DataServiceClient+DataServiceClientChannel.EndGetUsers (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00008] in C:\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\MyAppMobileProxy.cs:5021 
  at DataServiceClient.IDataService.EndGetUsers (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00001] in C:\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\MyAppMobileProxy.cs:3926 
  at DataServiceClient.OnEndGetUsers (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00001] in C:\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\MyAppMobileProxy.cs:3937 
  at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1+<InvokeAsync>c__AnonStorey0[TChannel].<>m__0 (System.IAsyncResult ar) [0x00006] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs:242 }
```

The line that this happens in is in the following : if (eventArgs.Error != null)
For the code below.  Just curious as to the cause to this?

```
    private void onGetUsersCompleted(object sender, GetUsersCompletedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        if (eventArgs.Error != null)
        {
            message = eventArgs.Error.ToString();
            App.Logger.LogError(eventArgs.Error, MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod());
        }
        else if (eventArgs.Cancelled)
        {
            message = "Request was cancelled";
        }
        else
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                var results = eventArgs.Result;
                foreach (User _user in results)
                {
                    tblUser user = new tblUser();
                    user.iUserID = _user.UserID;
                    user.nFName = _user.FirstName;
                    user.nLName = _user.LastName;
                    user.nLimitClientLocationID = _user.LimitToClientLocationID;
                    user.nLogin = _user.Login;
                    user.nPassword = _user.Password;
                    user.dModifiedDate = _user.ModifiedDate;
                    user.dCreationDate = _user.CreationDate;
                }
                if (results.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (isOnline)
                    {
                        //Save the users to the sqlite db
                        //Vm.SaveUsers();
                    }

                }
            }
            );
        }
    }
```

In the proxy class this is where the error initiates :

```
    public mycompany.net.services.thisapp._2016._01.User[] EndGetUsers(System.IAsyncResult result)
    {
        object[] _args = new object[0];
        mycompany.net.services.thisApp._2016._01.User[] _result = ((mycompany.net.services.thisApp._2016._01.User[])(base.EndInvoke("GetUsers", _args, result)));
        return _result;
    }
```

the wsdl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://mycompany.net/services/thisapp/2016/01" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" 
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" 
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://mycompany.net/services/thisapp/2016/01" name="DataService">
```

Web.Config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add 
          name="MyDatabase" 
          connectionString="Data Source=MyServer\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=****;Password=******"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient;"/>
      </connectionStrings>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding
              name="wsHttpMtomStandardBinding"
              maxReceivedMessageSize ="2000000"
              messageEncoding="Mtom">
              <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2000000"/>
              <reliableSession
                enabled="false"
                ordered="false"
                inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"/>
              <security mode="None" >
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
              </security>
            </binding>
            <binding
              name="wsHttpMtomSSLBinding"
              maxReceivedMessageSize ="2000000"
              messageEncoding="Mtom">
              <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2000000"/>
              <reliableSession
                enabled="false"
                ordered="false"
                inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"/>
              <security mode="Transport" >
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
              </security>
            </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding
              name="basicHttpStandardBinding"
              maxReceivedMessageSize ="2000000"
              messageEncoding="Mtom">
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
              </security>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="NormalBehavior">
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="32" maxConcurrentInstances="32" />
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="SecureBehavior">
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="32" maxConcurrentInstances="32" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
          <service
            name="MyApp.Services.DataService"
            behaviorConfiguration="SecureBehavior">
            <endpoint address="mex" 
                binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
                contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            <endpoint
              address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="MyApp.Contracts.IDataService"
              bindingConfiguration="basicHttpStandardBinding" />
          </service>
        </services>
        <protocolMapping>
          <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
          <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
          <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https"/>
          <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
        </protocolMapping>    
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <!--
            To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
            Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
          -->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
      </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```